# Use Angular in a non-Angular project

Tags: angular

I am trying to find out if there is a way to add a piece of Angular in a project built on different framework..

To be more specific, I have a .NET MVC project (Razor for the markup) from which I want to make some ajax calls and update bits of the UI. I rejected JQuery so far since I want to use a more modern approach(I am considering vanilla or vue because of the easy learning curve).

I thought the solution would be given by [Angular Elements](https://angular.io/guide/elements) so I could have something like:

```
<my-popup message="Use Angular!"></my-popup>
```

but it doesn't seem to work like that.

Again, my point is to use Angular in a non-Angular project.

Any suggestion would be welcome.

Comment: Are you using `angular` or `angularjs` ? You have tagged both and it can only be one.

Comment: I am considering Angular(2). Angularjs would be an option as well. Although, I am trying to plug Angular(2). But good point, my bad for putting both tags

Comment: `Angular > Angularjs` in my opinion. You can even mod your T4 template to generate you `.ts` classes which is really handy. Can't do anything like that with `angularjs`

Comment: Due to the architecture of Angular being a SPA, if you want to use Razor you are out of luck. The entire front end is brought down in a bundle the first time you hit the server and then the only communication it has with the server beyond that is via ajax calls; Even navigation is trapped in the SPA without requiring the server to process the request. Apparently there is a [server side](https://angular.io/guide/universal) option for Angular, however i've personally not heard great reviews and have not used it myself. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Zze That's the case. It's the other way round - render an Angular 'portion' inside an existing razor view. Like what we can do with a simple <script>what_ever</script> But I now what you mean. Thank you for taking he time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50627423/how-to-compile-angular-element-into-web-component-w-webpack-or-angular-cli/) on how to compile Angular Elements into a web component to use it.